# symfony2 how to upload file without doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, symfony-2.2

Is it possible to upload files in symfony2 WITHOUT using doctrine? With doctrine, its example is given here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Is there a simple way to upload files, like in core PHP we have move_uploaded_file() function with which we can move the uploaded to file after the form is submitted.

For now when I submit the form in symfony this is what I get in 'files' section of request array (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)

```
 [files] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag Object
        (
            [parameters:protected] => Array
                (
                    [upload_cover] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
                        (
                            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
                            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => secret_of_success.png
                            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/png
                            [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 157958
                            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
                            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\xampp\tmp\php3636.tmp
                            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php3636.tmp
                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After submitting the form, move the file to your desired directory and you will get a `File` object in return.

```
foreach($request->files as $uploadedFile) {
    $name = //...
    $file = $uploadedFile->move($directory, $name);
}
```

Take a look at [the API-Manual](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_move) for the full featured documentation of this class.

Comment: thanks for the reply, how can I create objecct $uploadfile, like this

$uploadfile= new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile();

Comment: After submitting the form they will already be around in `$request->files;`. So you can loop through this array and move every file you sent in the first place.

Comment: If I use above for loop, it seems to uploads temp file only, I selected a png for uploading in upload dir I see  temp file uploaded not the png image temp file has name php483.tmp. Am I missing something here?

Comment: ok got it, I guess I have to specify new file name as well along with the $direectory  $file = $uploadedFile->move($directory,'test.png');

Comment: Is this answer implying that each file has to have the same "$name"? Here are the methods that can be used to get the filename etc. http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

Comment: @Donovan no, answer is not implying to have the same name, we can have the different names for each uploaded file.