# Is possible to use PHP move_uploaded_file command in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, upload

I'm trying to upload file to server using jQuery and AJAX. I want handle using PHP command **move_uploaded_file**, but I don't now how to do it. It's possible to use this function from Symfony's controller?

Comment: [Please read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Tried once - few years ago when I was at very beginning of Symfony2. It was headache and I got burned up pretty good :(. So, no, avoid that at all costs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a symfony2 controller you will have access to a Request object. If you are uploading a file you should be able to handle the upload using this object:

```
namespace ACME\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller {
    // ...
    public function handleUploadAction(Request $reuqest) {
        foreach($request->files as $uploadedFile) {
            $name = 'uploaded-file-name.jpg';
            $file = $uploadedFile->move('/uploads/directory', $name);
        }
    }
}
```

A few things to notice here

1. Symfony2 will automatically inject the Request object to your controller
2. Take a look at this question [symfony2 how to upload file without doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019231/symfony2-how-to-upload-file-without-doctrine)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to use Symfony2 move function. I have to use move_uploaded_file function. It's possible to use ***move_uploaded_file*** the same way like you used ***move*** function in your code?

Comment: The method `UploadedFile::move` uses move_uploaded_file under the hood plus it checks for upload errors and will throw a proper exception if the operation fails: https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/File/UploadedFile.php#L241. Any particular reason why you want to use move_uploaded_file directly if there is a proper, well tested implementation of the functionality you need?